# May I, and how do I, change my mind about an accepted answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Suppose I accepted an answer to my question, and then a real doozie got submitted later, and I wish to change which one is marked as "accepted"?  Is this possible (if so, how)?  Is it frowned upon?  I couldn't find anything about this in the Help.

--- Edit --- The [similar question proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) is helpful but I would like to leave my question here, if I may, because its specificity was helpful for me and will hopefully be helpful for others.

Comment: I voted to close this question as a duplicate. There's no problem with leaving this question here (though closed), as it will still be able to be found through search, and can actually be especially helpful to people (presumably, like you) who searched for the other question but couldn't find it because it was missing certain keywords that you (hopefully) made sure to include in your question. <[Insert link to blog post here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262077/266359)>

Comment: This is the blog post I wanted to link to: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/. I really recommend you read it, it's a good one :)

Comment: @Shokhet Thanks, that was fun reading.  Anyway, I have no objection to this being closed now; as I understand it, if that happens, the question and the two helpful existing answers will still be there for posterity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer):

> Accepting an answer **is not meant to be a definitive and final statement** indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally, but not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

That said: you *can* change your accepted answer, and you are allowed to. Simply uncheck the 'accepted' check mark.

Is it frowned upon: yes, by the user whose answer you unaccepted. You shouldn't care too much. One advise though: don't be too quick when it comes to accepting an answer. Just take the time to let people answer. Nothing is as annoying as a user who immediately accepts the first answer he gets. Also don't switch a dozen times if you are in doubt.

Answer (score 9):

> Is this possible (if so, how)?

Yes, this is possible. Just click the green tick mark next to the answer you have accepted to un-accept it.

Then accept the other answer.

> Is it frowned upon?

No, not at all. If the other answer is the best one in your eyes.