# Where's the Strangedupe blog post?

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

Previously, in order to explain the benefits of (certain limited kinds of) duplication on Stack Exchange sites, I've seen a blog.stackoverflow blogpost with the words "Dr. Strangedupe" in the title.

The post comes up in a search on the new blog, but ["can't find the page I'm looking for."](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

[image: search results including the title of the Strangedupe article]

[image: page on blog.stackoverflow.com with the url that should belong to the Strangedupe article, but claims that it "can't find the page I'm looking for"]

**Can we please bring this post back?** I'd love to link to it when [commenting on duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262067/may-i-and-how-do-i-change-my-mind-about-an-accepted-answer/262068#comment854651_262067), to reassure the questioner that there is value in not deleting their question because of search terms, but the blog post explained it a lot better than I could in a comment.

Comment: Ignore the fact that Chrome has both AdBlock and AdBlock Plus -- that has nothing to do with me. This is my mother's computer :P

Comment: Nope. We're silently judging you.

Comment: Bunch of other older posts are gone too. Looking...

Comment: It's working for me here - I can see the post. Maybe it was in the middle of a build or something at the time it was 404ing, because there haven't been any changes in the last 40 minutes.

Comment: @AlexWarren It works for me now, too

Comment: Voting to reopen, the bug keeps happening and better be investigated properly instead of having hundreds of blog posts disappear on weekly basis.

Comment: [Another example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264528/broken-link-from-moderator-pro-tempore-page-to-theory-of-moderation-page)

Comment: Note the [comment on that post showing that an older version of that blog page still works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264528/broken-link-from-moderator-pro-tempore-page-to-theory-of-moderation-page?noredirect=1#comment860831_264528). Is this relevant to those working on a fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[It's back now](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). That and lots of other old posts like to disappear when the blog does partial builds. That'll be investigated further.

Comment: This [keeps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264247/attribution-required-link-to-a-blog-post-on-the-bottom-of-every-page-is-giving) [happening](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264243/broken-blog-link-on-pages-with-lists-of-moderators). Any chance for a permanent fix that will also prevent blog posts from disappearing in the future, instead of letting them disappear, wait for someone to notice and report, then let hours pass before the pages are put back?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yup. Trying figure out why these weird partial builds keep happening so we can fix it for good. Just need Jon Chan to get his coffee and take a look...

Comment: Thanks, just hope he won't run out of coffee while hunting the bug down...

Comment: Looks like Jon failed, and it's [Anna's turn now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266336/stack-overflow-valued-associate-404#comment864133_266336).