# Broken blog link on pages with lists of moderators

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, broken-link, users-page

The page https://anime.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators has a link like this:

[democratic moderator elections.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/)

which doesn't seem to exist anymore.

This is the same on [other sites' user pages for moderators too.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)

And also on [the overall moderator page on SE](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators)

Comment: @ShadowWizard what do u think of creating ONE post for Blog broken links, images, bugs, etc. then everyone can answer to that with their findings. Just like what SE team puts a post for feedback on new release where everyone answers. I have already reported few blog related problems and have at least another 8-10 new ones. dMay be high-rep. like you can put this for all.

Comment: Same thing it always is, @ShadowWizard

Comment: *trying to read @Shog9 mind* **SUCCESS**! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262077/wheres-the-strangedupe-blog-post.