# "Attribution Required" link to a blog post on the bottom of every page is giving a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, attribution, 404-not-found

https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/attribution-required/ gives a 404, and doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Comment: I figured they'd just removed old posts. I'm sure that was on purpose, but surely keeping a link to a removed post on every single StackOverflow page is a bug.