# Broken link from Moderator Pro Tempore page to Theory of Moderation page

Tags: bug, blog, 404-not-found

On the [Moderator Pro Tempore](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) blog page, there is a link to the [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) blog page. However, following this link results in "Sorry, we can't find that page that you're looking for."

Comment: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/ certainly doesn't pass the eye test.

Comment: @chirlu thanks for pointing that out - I've added this post as a comment to that one to show that it's still happening.

Comment: This one https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/ still works ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for pointing that out - I've linked to your comment from the other meta post (that this is a duplicate of) in case it's relevant to those working on a fix for the general problem.

Comment: This (as well as 20 something more) are going to be fixed tomorrow, I just kicked off a couple pull requests as well. Thanks for the reports, it was in fact the WP relative URL that was causing the problem.