# Stack Overflow Valued Associate #404

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, blog

So, I was poking at [Kevin's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose) and followed the link for [Stack Overflow Valued Associate #00004](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-000004/) which brought me to a page:

[image]

Until such a time that these links work, please change Kevin's profile to be employee #404.

(to any who suggest I should have used the feedback site link, [it links to this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com).)

P.S.:

- [Shog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/welcome-valued-associate-josh-heyer/)
- [balpha](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associates-00006-and-00007)
- [Robert](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/04/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00005/)
- [Jon](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2013/08/please-welcome-jon-ericson-community-manager/)
- [Geoff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas)

I'm sure there are others too.

Comment: +1 Add Marc Gravell too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/23354/marc-gravell

Comment: Looks like everything posted before April 22, 2014 disappeared.

Comment: Ugh, that might be my fault. I did a blog build earlier today... and I vaguely recall "sometimes posts disappear!" being a thing, but I couldn't possibly tell you how or why. I will see what's what ASAP.

Comment: @AnnaLear the default _config has limit_posts: 50, unlike the _blog.config. That tripped me up locally and could be related.

Comment: I reproduced this issue as well trying to find this post https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Comment: @D.G. Our builds *should* be running with _blog.config: `Jekyll build --config '_blog.config.yml' --no-watch`. Looking into why that is sometimes not respected.

Comment: @AnnaLear Mr Hyde, obviously.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the curious, here's why once in a while the incorrect configuration file was loaded: Jekyll uses a little library called [Mercenary](https://github.com/jekyll/mercenary) that, among other things, is responsible for passing the parsed command line options to Jekyll. Mercenary had an [obscure bug](https://github.com/jekyll/mercenary/pull/35) that caused these options to be incorrect; this bug was fixed in [Mercenary 0.3.4](https://github.com/jekyll/mercenary/releases/tag/v0.3.4).

The Jekyll installation on our build servers is based on [PortableJekyll](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll), and while some of the included gems (notably, Jekyll itself) have been updated over the versions that are shipped in PortableJekyll, Mercenary is still on 0.3.3, and thus still includes that bug. We'll be sure to update that today.

Comment: wonder what would happen when Mercenary version gets to 4.0.4

Comment: @gnat Prior to that, 4.0.2 would be more concerning for many.

Answer (score 6):

Good news/meh news: I kicked off another build and that one seems to have used the right config file, so the posts are back. (Yay!) But, this also means we still don't know why this build *sometimes* fails.

We use TeamCity, and we're seeing the following in the build log for a bad build:

```
[Jekyll build] Jekyll build --config '_blog.config.yml' --no-watch
[Jekyll build] Configuration file: C:/BuildAgent/work/a24cc5c53d3309db/blog/_config.yml
[Jekyll build]             Source: C:/BuildAgent/work/a24cc5c53d3309db/blog
[Jekyll build]        Destination: C:/BuildAgent/work/a24cc5c53d3309db/blog/_site
```

vs a good build:

```
[Jekyll build] Jekyll build --config '_blog.config.yml' --no-watch
[Jekyll build] Configuration file: _blog.config.yml
[Jekyll build]             Source: C:/BuildAgent/work/a24cc5c53d3309db/blog
[Jekyll build]        Destination: C:/BuildAgent/work/a24cc5c53d3309db/blog/_site
```

So... that'll be a fun one to figure out.

Comment: Just curious, what happened to Jon Chan?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nothing AFAIK, what do you mean?

Comment: @balpha as far as I know, he's the one working on the new blog as [abby also mentioned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262077/wheres-the-strangedupe-blog-post#comment860033_262079) :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard He's the main dev on the blog, but [a lot of us](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/graphs/contributors) do things on it (and that list doesn't even show infrastructure work like the one at play here).

Comment: @balpha wow, never imagined so many people are involved. Cheers!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm alive I promise

Comment: Hey @Jon those are awesome news! :D